# iscroll input and scrolling on computer

Tags: jquery, iscroll

I'm using iScroll 4 for a mobile web app. I've got the app working perfectly on mobile and ipad, however I also want the app still to work on computer.

The issue I have is that the scroll doesn't work on computer and I can't select text input areas to type anything in. I'm fairly sure this is down to the way iScoll works so need a workaround code.

Because of that, I'm not showing any code here as there isn't any specific bit that would help. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This provides you selecting input fields:

```
function initScroller() {
    myScroller = new iScroll('wrapper', {
        snap: true,
        momentum: false,
        hScrollbar: false,
        vScrollbar: false,
        hScroll: true,
        checkDOMChanges: true,
        onBeforeScrollStart: preventTextarea
    });
}

var preventTextarea = function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;

    if (target && (target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'CANVAS') ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```